# Scaling large data in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making a Q&A site. I have three models for now:

```
Question
Answer
User
```

Both Question and Answer can be voted for, so I need a way to store who voted on the model, to prevent multiple votes on one model by same user.

Would be a good idea to create a vote model? Where either the question_id or the answer_id will be empty in each. I'm afraid that this will create a lot of junk and slow the application down.

My other idea is to store the user_id in a hash in the Answer and in the Question.
If the user is already present in the hash it prevents voting. Or store the answer and question ids in the user.

What would be the Rails4 way to be fast but store most user interactions in models. What can be KISS, DRY and fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [polymorphic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) model if you have multiple models the `Vote` can refer to.

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, as: :voteable
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, as: :voteable
end
```

I don't think you have to worry about the speed for quite a while if you use indexes on the associations. Just put this snippet in a migration and you should be good to go!

```
add_index :votes, [:voteable_name, :voteable_id]
```